# How to move a widget to a specific place?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have an icon. I want to put it in top left of the container. I already tried `alignment` and `stack` and `column(mainaxisalignment.start)` , none of them was helpful, for now it is working fine but when text is bigger it comes to left center of the container widget. This is my code:

```
   Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.grey[300],
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(5.0)),
          ),
          child: Row(
            children: [
              Expanded(
                  child: Icon(
                    Icons.warning,
                    color: Colors.red,
                  ),
                ),
              Expanded(
                flex: 9,
                  child: Directionality(
                    textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
                    child: Text(
                      '''day every  rough places will be made plain.''',
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        );
```

What is the best idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add crossAxisAlignment property to your Row.

```
             crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
```